# In Windows 10, "Do not turn off system power after a Windows system shutdown has occurred" group policy has no effect: workarounds?

Tags: windows-10, shutdown

I have a PC encased in a box, so the power switch is not accessible. I want to set it to have the old style "you can now shutdown your pc" screen. The reason is that if an user accidentally shutdown it, he can just unplug it and then it will turn it on again thanks to the "turn on after power loss" setting in BIOS. Otherwise the user needs to take a screwdriver and open the box.

There's a group policy called "Do not turn off system power after a Windows system shutdown has occurred". But it doesn't do anything, when I shutdown Windows, the PC turns off.

There [used to be an hotfix](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2660114/do-not-turn-off-system-power-after-a-windows-system-shutdown-has-occur) for Windows 7, but now it's no more available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just noticed that, if I turn off the PC from the start menu, the PC turns off, but I get the intended behavior if it gets turned off with

```
shutdown -s -t 0
```

Except that you have a black screen instead of the "you can now turn off your PC" screen, so it might be a problem when it installs updates, as it could be installing something with black screen instead of being ready to be turned off.

Answer (score -1):

The reason this happens, is the pc is not technically shutdown, but placed into hibernation.

In windows 10, this is called Fast Startup, or Hybrid Shutdown.

If you disable Hybrid shutdown, you can just use the shutdown from the startmenu as intended.

To do so, go to your Power Settings, Extra Power Settings, Change the state of the powerbutton, At the top, click the link: change additional settings, then at the bottom, uncheck Fast Startup enabled (recommended)

Comment: doesn't work, fast startup disabled, rebooted twice, it does shutdown the system instead of keeping it on as if invoked from shutdown.exe